# How to return XML node inner text comparing it to same descendant?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a xml file like this:

```
<Tests>
   <Test>
      <Name>Test1</Name>
      <Type>A</Type>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <Name>Test2</Name>
      <Type>A</Type>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <Name>Test3</Name>
      <Type>B</Type>
   </Test>
</Tests>
```

How can I return a string array or list which only contains name of the `Test` which theire type is `A`?

I am trying with this code but no success!

```
XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Tests/Test[Type = 'A']/Name)
```

Comment: Your XPath expression is correct. Can you elaborate on what you mean by `no success`?

Comment: At the moment it returns all the `Name` nodes, I will look again and report back.

Comment: That's because your XPath expression indeed matches `Name` elements. You should remove `/Name` in order to match the `Test` elements instead.

Comment: You mean I have to use `XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Tests/Test[Type = 'A'])`     ?So how can I point to the `Name` node to read it's inner text? can you explain a bit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression in your question matches `Name` elements. If you want to match `Test` elements instead, you have to remove the `/Name` part:

```
XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Tests/Test[Type = 'A']);
```

If you want to use an `XPathNavigator`, from there, you can call [MoveToChild()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b08z3h9.aspx) to point the navigator to the `Name` elements:

```
foreach (XPathNavigator elemNav in it) {
    elemNav.MoveToChild("Name", "");
    string name = elemNav.Value;
    // Do something with 'name'...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to try linq2xml?

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
```

///////////

```
XElement root = new XElement("Tests",
  new XElement("Test",
    new XElement("Name", "Test1"),
    new XElement("Type", "A")),
  new XElement("Test",
    new XElement("Name", "Test2"),
    new XElement("Type", "A")),
  new XElement("Test",
    new XElement("Name", "Test3"),
    new XElement("Type", "B")));

string[] result = (from xe in root.Elements()
                   where xe.Element("Type").Value.Equals("A")
                   select xe.Element("Name").Value).ToArray();
```